# How to install php-xml extension in windows?

Tags: php, laravel, web, php-extension

I'm trying to install laravel-excel on my laravel project. That library requires below php extensions to be enabled.

- PHP extension php_zip
- PHP extension php_xml
- PHP extension php_gd2
- PHP extension php_iconv
- PHP extension php_simplexml
- PHP extension php_xmlreader
- PHP extension php_zlib

I changed the php.ini accordingly. But I can't download related .dll files to copy to ext folder.
Do you have any place to download these?

Comment: what software you used for sever ? different software has there own location

Comment: I just installed php in windows and using built in php server for serve laravel application

Comment: you if you install php `using built in php` then you must know php location ?

Comment: Yes i know the location. But php_xml does not come with default php installation. Where i can download them?

Comment: Most of those extensions are built-in. You can't even disable them unless you recompile PHP from source. What is your PHP version and were did you get it from?

Comment: php8 should contain these in the library folder

Comment: yes i found them on when i install php8... Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download them from PHP Extension Community Library ([PECL](https://pecl.php.net/))

For example this is the php_zip source that you need:
https://pecl.php.net/package/zip/1.12.4/windows

Similarly you can get the rest of them.